# Can I use placeholder in <input type="time"/>

Tags: html

Can I use placeholder in `<input type="time"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can

The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field

it depents how the browser behaves to the

```
<input type="time"/>
```

for example chromium shows

```
--:-- --
```

by defualt but firefox shows the placeholder value you have set

check here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab9Ed/)

Comment: firefox also shows --:-- so that's not the case any more

Answer (score 6):

Placeholder does not work with input type time however you can Prefilled data.

```html
Just time:
<input type="time" value="13:00" step="900">
```

Answer (score 5):

If you add an id or class to the input, you can add text to the input `type="time"` field by using `:before` selector.

For example:

```css
#timepicker:before {
   content: 'Time:';
   margin-right: .6em;
   color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="timepicker">
```

Comment: Just tried this method, but the input will still display 'Time:' even after a value is picked. any idea to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to change input type on focus from text to time.
Yes this is a little hacky way but it works. Apply correct styling and you will get result

```html
Just time:
<input type="text" placeholder="Demo time" step="900" onfocus="this.type='time'">
```

The main difference is that in this case required attribute is used to be able use css selector

```css
input[type="time"]:not(:valid):before {
  content:'Time:';
  margin-right:.6em;
  color:#9d9d9d;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" required />
```

Answer (score 2):

Placeholder does not work in input time, but you can do the same functionality as placeholder by this

```css
input[type="time"] {
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 150px;
}

input[type="time"]:before {
    content: 'HH:mm ss';
    color: #9d9d9d;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 70px;
}

input[type="time"]:focus:before {
    width: 0;
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<h1>The placeholder for input time</h1>
<input type="time">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you cannot. But if you do,it won't work in IE and firefox browsers as they do not support  `<input type="time">`. And hence they will be treated as `<input type="text">` with the placeholder you give.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

Small css trick :P

```css
input[type="time"] {
    background: #fff;
    height:30px;
    min-width: 150px;
}

input[type="time"]:before {
    content: 'My Placeholder';
    color: #9d9d9d;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    height: 18px;
}

input[type="time"]:hover:before {
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<input type="time"  />
```

Answer (score -2):

example :
<type="text" placeholder="Timestamp" onfocus="this.type='time'" onblur="this.type='text'">

Use onfocus() and onblur() to do that

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.