# Time type and placeholder in html5

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox, placeholder

How can I set a placeholder in a textbox with type="time"?
Currently, it displays the time input format like --:--, but I'd like it to show "Start Time" and "End time" inside the textbox itself, not on an external label.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="StartingHour" Type="time" runat="server" placeholder="Start Time" required="required" />
```

Right now, it displays --:-- instead of the placeholder text. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you want to set placeholder - when losing focus or at all times? Currently the `time` input control placeholder depends on browser implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `placeholder` attribute setting depends on how the client browsers behave with `<input type="time" />`, but if you want to show placeholders when the user not selecting input control, you may try this workaround:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="StartingHour" runat="server" placeholder="Start Time" required="required" />
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
// when getting focus
$('#<%= StartingHour.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
    $(this).attr('type', 'time'); 
});

// when losing focus
$('#<%= StartingHour.ClientID %>').focusout(function () {
    $(this).attr('type', 'text'); 
});
```

**Note:** The same way can be used for control `EndingHour`'s placeholder.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/75phkmd6/3/)

**Update 1:**

If you want to use common prefix (like `txtHour`) to input controls, you may set `ClientID` mode to `Static` and use the prefix as selector:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHour1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Time" required="required" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtHour2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Time" required="required" />
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
// when getting focus
$('input[id^="txtHour"]').focus(function () {
    $(this).attr('type', 'time'); 
});

// when losing focus
$('input[id^="txtHour"]').focusout(function () {
    $(this).attr('type', 'text'); 
});
```

Or use a shared CSS class assigned for all related textbox controls:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHour1" runat="server" CssClass="hour" placeholder="Time" required="required" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtHour2" runat="server" CssClass="hour" placeholder="Time" required="required" />
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
// when getting focus
$('.hour').focus(function () {
    $(this).attr('type', 'time'); 
});

// when losing focus
$('.hour').focusout(function () {
    $(this).attr('type', 'text'); 
});
```

Similar issue: [Can I use placeholder in <input type="time"/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191875/can-i-use-placeholder-in-input-type-time)

Comment: Nice workaround! But how can I change the jscript to apply it to every control id starting with a specific string? Let's say all my time textbox have as prefix "txtHour", can I use the same jscript without have to specify the actual ID of each one?

Comment: In the case you have control ID like `txtHour1`, `txtHour2`, etc., you can use that prefix as jQuery selector like `$('input[id^="txtHour"]')`. However, this works only if the ClientID mode set to `static`, hence I suggest you to use a common CSS class and use it as selector.